# disabling certain options in a combobox based on database query

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So this is a hard one, i am doing a mangment software for a warehouse and i save the location of items on the shelves as plain number in my database, ie i have column row,shelf and ledge, and each one is a number (the total is of each is determined first) to say i have 11 rows, 5 shelves and each shelf has 5 ledges.
now my problem is i locate an item in row 1 shelf 1 and ledge 1, all good now what i want to do is for the program to detect that there is already an item in that location and when i try to save another item it just disables out or just removes that option in the combobox.

here is how i load the comboboxes

```
dgvAux.DataSource = datos.consultar("select top 1 rows from warehouse");
        int rows= Convert.ToInt32(dgvAux.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        for (int i = 1; i < rows+ 1; i++)
        {


            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "Row " + i.ToString();
            item.Value = i;

            cboRow.Items.Add(item);

            cboRow.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
        dgvAux.DataSource = datos.consultar("select top 1 shelves from warehouse");
        int shelves= Convert.ToInt32(dgvAux.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        for (int i = 1; i < shelves+ 1; i++)
        {


            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "Shelf" + i.ToString();
            item.Value = i;

            cboShelves.Items.Add(item);

            cboShelves.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
        dgvAux.DataSource = datos.consultar("select top 1 ledges from almacenes");
        int ledges= Convert.ToInt32(dgvAux.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        for (int i = 1; i < ledges+ 1; i++)
        {


            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "Ledge" + i.ToString();
            item.Value = i;

            cboLedge.Items.Add(item);

            cboLedge.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
```

i know its not the best way to do it, but is the way i was able to make it work

Comment: It's probably better to just remove the item from the list.

Comment: Be careful here...you have top 1 but no order by.

Comment: draw datagridview cont 55 rows and 5 columns 
array (x,y,z

Comment: draw datagridview content  55 rows and 5 columns 
position(x,y,z) 
x= number row in waerhouse 
y= number shelve in row 
z= number ledge in  shelve

x= (datagridview rowIndex/5)+1
y=((y*5)-rowIndex)
z= column Index

Comment: @محمدالنعيمي sorry but what do you mean by that code? could you perhaps respond to the post and explain? i dont see how that would disable/remove the optioons

Comment: You can divide the store into a matrix where each element represents a location in the store
The site can be represented in the matrix:
B = Ari (x, y, z)
As long as you have 11 rows and each row has 5 shelves and each shelf has 5 edges

Comment: @محمدالنعيمي i get that, i dont get how are you removing the locations that are already in use from the combobox

Comment: How is the location of the item represented in the items table?

Comment: How is the location of the item represented in the items table?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an event handler on each time a combobox is changed that will check the availability of all options in further comboboxes
Like so if you choose a shelf number, a check is done for all the available space in that shelf and will remove the irrelevant or already full spaces (if statement or switch case to add and remove items from comboboxes)

Answer (score 0):

As guys are pointing out in the comments, it is not a good design to have disabled items in combo list.
However there is property [`IsEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) which you need to set to `False` and that's it. You need to have algorithm to decide which one to set to disable.

Comment: We don't know if this is WPF, WinForms, or ASP.Net, etc.

Comment: sorry, just added the tag, its winforms. and i also think its better to remove the options from the combobox, it just didnt cross my mind for some reason